# Mouseover on image using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Edit:

```
FF version 19.0.2
Selenium WebDriver version: 2.31.2.0
```

How to verify that image hover is working using Webdriver? So I have 5 stars and each stars represent different title and I'm looking for a way to hover over those stars.

I used the below code but I dont see hovering over the image....

I have used following code snippets to

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
WebElement tagElement = driver.findElement(By.CssSelector("#divctl00....."));
builder.moveToElement(tagElement).build().perform();
```

Comment: What version of FF and selenium are you using?

Comment: Is this divctl00..... proper Id of that image?

Comment: updated my question, @santosh - thats correct

Answer (score 0):

Mouseover doesn't work if you use old version of Webdriver and new version of Firefox. please share your versions.

Comment: upgrade your firefox to v20 and check.

Comment: i updated to ff 20 but dont see its hovering over the image even i have sleep for 2 seconds

Comment: could you share your page html. There may be something wrong with element identification.

Comment: Firefox 20 wasn't released when Selenium 2.31.0 was released (the current Java version), or when 2.31.2 was released (The current version for .NET).  So it's not realistic to expect Selenium to work flawlessly with FireFox 20.  I would stick with FireFox 19.0.2 until the next version of Selenium has been released, it's likely native events will be broken with FF20 and Selenium 2.31.0.  The second thing I notice is that your code looks like Java, but you are giving a .Net version of selenium.  Which language binding are you using?